# Maven Pom.xml not running

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pom.xml

I try to run my test as -mvn test, it is showing as build is success but , No Source to Compile.Down I have attached my both pom and Result file.

**Output :**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Wepaythemax 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Wepaythemax ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rck\git\repository3\Wepaythemax\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ Wepaythemax ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Wepaythemax ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Wepaythemax ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Wepaythemax ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.051 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-20T18:37:53+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/114M
```

**Pom.xml File**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Wepaythemax</groupId>
  <artifactId>Wepaythemax</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.5</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>selenium-tests</id>
      <build>
         <plugins>
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                  <suiteXmlFiles>
                     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                  </suiteXmlFiles>
               </configuration>
            </plugin>     
         </plugins>
      </build>
   </profile>
</profiles>
</project>
```

Help Me out, Where I have done Mistake, I can't find out. I'm Trying to Figure it out.Also I have attached a Screenshot Where the My testng.xml file is placed

[image: Location For testng File]

Comment: Your directory `src/test` only has a `resources` sub-directory. No `java` sub-directory that could potentially hold the _sources_.

Comment: Then how to place my testng file and where? @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: You maven is not speaking about _resources_ - like the `testng.xml` file. It is telling you, that there are no _sources_ to compile. Your screenshot tells us, you don't have any sources. So what are you actually asking?

Comment: source location `src/main/java` unit tests in `src/test/java` ...

Comment: it seems that the`testng.xml` file is at the correct place. There still are no sources, neither under `src/main/java` nor under `src/test/java`. This is what maven is telling you.

Comment: When i place my testng.xml file under src/main/java, it is telling me  "Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date" @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: GRRRRR.... I am speaking about _sources_, not _resources_. I already told you, that the file `testng.xml` is at the _right_ place because it is a resource. What exactly is it that you don't understand here?

Comment: Shit, Now Running, i Missed one File. @Seelenvirtuose now only i catched it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no sources to compile, means no java file in src/main/java or src/test/java. 
sources are in src/main/java, sources is different from resources, which means .xml,etc.

Comment: Yea, Got it One Mistake made me fuzzy!